# MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart() Как отправить PUT запрос?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

Код ниже работает хорошо, но посылает `POST` запросы, как мне отпроавить`PUT`?

```
@Test
void updateDish() throws Exception {
    MockMultipartFile emptyFile
            = new MockMultipartFile(
            "image",
            "image.jpg",
            MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,
            new byte[0]
    );
    DishCreationDto dishCreationDto = getDishCreationDto();
    mockMvc.perform(multipart("/admin/dishes")
                    .file(emptyFile)
                    .flashAttr("dish", dishCreationDto)
                    .with(csrf()))
            .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/admin/dishes"));
    Mockito.verify(dishService, Mockito.times(1)).saveDish(dishCreationDto);
}
```

Comment: @RomanC это не отвечает на вопрос, я явно POST не вызываю, так работает MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart()

Comment: что такое `mockMvc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно создать кастомный билдер, который установит метод `PUT` в HTTP-запросе:

```java
MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder putMultipart = (MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder)
        MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/admin/dishes")
        .with(rq -> { rq.setMethod("PUT"); return rq; });

mockMvc.perform(putMultipart
        .file(emptyFile)
        .flashAttr("dish", dishCreationDto)
        .with(csrf()))
    .andExpect(redirectedUrl("/admin/dishes"));
```